# how to specify external schema in processContents=lax

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xmlbeans

I have a generic schema that defines a section like this:

```
<xs:element name="detail">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>    

    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:anyAttribute processContents="skip"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I've been reading up on this stuff for most of the day, but still can't seem to wrap my head around how to get down to the fields that would be found in the actual xml document under the detail element.

I know that it could look like this:

```
<detail>
   <drawing>
      <name="test"/>
    </drawing>
</detail>
```

or

```
<detail>
   <icon>
      <icon_name="testIcon"/>
      <icon_image="iconImage.jpg"/>
    </icon>
</detail>
```

xmlbeans doesn't have a way of knowing what is going into the details element since it is a wildcard, so it does not provide me a way of diving into those elements.  the xmlbeans site was indicating that i modify the document i have read in to move the wildcard elements up a level, but that doesn't seem cut and dry.
I could also modify the schema to do an element ref on the elements that could be there for my particular code.  Thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Since the detail element can contain any valid XML you are limited to either using some generic way of accessing the contents (XPath, DOM traversal or similar) or by specifically trying to match each child to a specfic schema (preferrably by using unique namespaces). Children matching a known schema could then be fed to your favourite library that generates objects out of XML.

Another option could, as you say, be to specify each valid child type in the schema (optionally with a wildcard on the bottom for extensibility purposes).